How to better analyze the correlation between binary and log-scaled data?
Imagine I have two datasets as shown in the figure:

data1 is an array of zeroes and ones, while data2 is an array of real values (shown in log scale, ranging from $10^{-12}$ to $10^5$).
It appears there might be some sort of negative correlation between these datasets. Using Pearson's R, I obtained a correlation coefficient of -0.0583 with a p-value of 6.595e-172, indicating a weak negative correlation.
I am looking for a more robust statistical method to describe the relationship between these datasets, as the Pearson correlation might not fully capture what we observe visually.
I have considered Spearman's rank correlation and the point-biserial correlation but am uncertain about the best approach or how to proceed. Could you provide guidance on the most appropriate statistical tests or analyses to better understand this relationship?

If you told us what these data represent, that would increase the probabiliry og getting some useful response, so please do so, by editing the post, not only as comments, as comments can be easily overseen and may be deleted. But maybe look into logistic regression?
